# Assign specific DHCP options to client in dnsmasq

Tags: dhcp, dnsmasq

I found that to create a static lease, I need to use

> dhcp-host=aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff,192.168.111.50

stanza in the configuration file.

However, in addition, I need to apply specific DHCP options to this client (different domain name than default). Based on https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/dhcp#classifying_clients_and_assigning_individual_options1 I assume that it is possible, but I can't find the relevant config file options for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a domain that is different to that of the dnsmasq server itself to either a single IP or a range of addresses with the following syntax:

```
domain=<domain>[,<address range>]
```

From the [man page](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html):

> The address range can be of the form (ip address),(ip address) or (ip
>   address/netmask) or just a single (ip address).

So, for a single client as described in the question, you want:

```
domain=domain.com,192.168.111.50
```